# Positioning an image within a header

Tags: html, css

I would like to position the image inside the header. Currently, the top portion of the image is displayed and I want to display the middle part of the image. The `top` attribute makes the image clip over the parent's box. Please take a look at my code.

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header-inner">

        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: grey;
}

.header-inner {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../images/img.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the middle part of the image you could use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) on `.header-inner`. You can specify a custom percentage or simply `center` it.

```css
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Ah I used ```background-position: center;``` previously but didn't think of entering custom values for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you set `position: absolute` then block will be over the others. So just set `z-index: -1;` to `.header-inner`